# ImageView not showing image on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, image, imageview, device

I am trying to create an interface for my application. In layout preview from eclipse everything is ok but when I test the application on the real device the two ImageViews doesn't show the images. I make Android application for 2 years but it is the first time I encounter this problem.
Screenshot from the eclipse layout preview:
[image]

And here is a screenshot from my tablet with no changes made to the code:
[image]

The xml code I use is simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/right_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:weightSum="11" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/upper_container" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="12312"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/video_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_container" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I created a separate RelativeLayout with the background image and I put the ImageView with the button over it. It worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

also change height and width of imageview to fill parent.like:

```
android:layout_height="Fill_parent"
android:layout_widtht="Fill_parent"
```

Comment: It doesn't change a thing.